# Type Casting Issue with List View OnItemDataBound Event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

On Page Load Event I am trying to do

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FeedUrl);
                   SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

                   lstViewNewsFeeds.DataSource = feed.Items;
                   lstViewNewsFeeds.DataBind(); 
         }
```

---

```
protected void lstViewNewsFeeds_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Instantiate listview control object.
            ListViewDataItem lvDataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

            at this line given exception
            **DataRowView drvItem = (DataRowView)lvDataItem.DataItem;** 

            //Make sure that data item is binding with listview.
            if (lvDataItem.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {

                SyndicationItem item = e.Item.DataItem as SyndicationItem;

                LinkButton linkButtonTitle = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbNewsTitle");
                Panel panelNewsDescContent = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("panelNewsDescription"); 

                // Make sure that linkButtonTile is referenced.
                if (linkButtonTitle != null)
                {
                   // linkButtonTitle.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Title);
                    linkButtonTitle.Text = Convert.ToString(drvItem["Title"]);
                }
                // Make sure that panel object is referenced.
                if (panelNewsDescContent != null)
                {
                    Label lblBox = new Label();
                   // lblBox.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Summary);
                    panelNewsDescContent.Controls.Add(lblBox);
                }

                //Label l = e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
                //l.Text = item.Title.Text;
                //HyperLink hl = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink;
                //hl.Text = item.Title.Text;
                //hl.NavigateUrl = item.Links[0].Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            Response.Write(ee.Message);
        }
```

Giving Error:

> 'System.Data.DataRowView'.Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem' to type
>   'System.Data.DataRowView'.Unable to cast object of type

I am not able to understand how i remove this error. Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

[`SyndicationFeed.Items` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.items.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>`, so you should cast it to [`SyndicationItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.aspx) instead.

```
SyndicationItem item = (SyndicationItem)lvDataItem.DataItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this works fine.

```
 SyndicationItem item = e.Item.DataItem as SyndicationItem;  




 protected void lstViewNewsFeeds_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Instantiate listview control object.
                ListViewDataItem lvDataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
                //DataRowView drvItem = (DataRowView)lvDataItem.DataItem; 
                //SyndicationItem item = (SyndicationItem)lvDataItem.DataItem;

                //Make sure that data item is binding with listview.
                if (lvDataItem.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
                {

                    SyndicationItem item = e.Item.DataItem as SyndicationItem;

                    LinkButton linkButtonTitle = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbNewsTitle");
                    Panel panelNewsDescContent = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("panelNewsDescription"); 

                    // Make sure that linkButtonTile is referenced.
                    if (linkButtonTitle != null)
                    {
                       // linkButtonTitle.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Title);
                        linkButtonTitle.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Title.Text);
                    }
                    // Make sure that panel object is referenced.
                    if (panelNewsDescContent != null)
                    {
                        Label lblBox = new Label();
                        lblBox.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Summary);
                        panelNewsDescContent.Controls.Add(lblBox);
                    }

                    //Label l = e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
                    //l.Text = item.Title.Text;
                    //HyperLink hl = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink;
                    //hl.Text = item.Title.Text;
                    //hl.NavigateUrl = item.Links[0].Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                Response.Write(ee.Message);
            }
}
```

By The way thanks all of you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void lstViewNewsFeeds_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Make sure that data item is binding with listview.
            if (lvDataItem.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {

                SyndicationItem item = e.Item.DataItem as SyndicationItem;

                LinkButton linkButtonTitle = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbNewsTitle");
                Panel panelNewsDescContent = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("panelNewsDescription"); 

                // Make sure that linkButtonTile is referenced.
                if (linkButtonTitle != null)
                {
                   linkButtonTitle.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Title);
                }
                // Make sure that panel object is referenced.
                if (panelNewsDescContent != null)
                {
                    Label lblBox = new Label();
                    lblBox.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Summary);
                    panelNewsDescContent.Controls.Add(lblBox);
                }

                Label l = e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
                l.Text = item.Title.Text;
                HyperLink hl = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1") as HyperLink;
                hl.Text = item.Title.Text;
                hl.NavigateUrl = item.Links[0].Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            Response.Write(ee.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kapil for your answer but i have already used this see below my answer ...But by the way thanks ...and if (lvDataItem.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)  here in lvDataItem.ItemType lvDataItem is not found in current context. so we need to add ListViewDataItem lvDataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;